# Parse background job fails when scheduled but succeeds when manually started

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a problem with my background job, which should be scheduled every night at `0:00`. These past two days, the job failed when it was scheduled:

> E2015-09-03T00:00:11.525Z]v24 Ran job deleteAndSaveScores with: Input: {} Result: success/error was not called

But when I start it manually through the dashboard, it doesn't fail and works perfectly:

> I2015-09-04T07:15:25.942Z]v24: Ran job deleteAndSaveScores with: Input: {} Result: Migration completed successfully.

Here is my job:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("deleteAndSaveScores", function(request, status) {
 // Query for all scores
 var ScoresCalc = Parse.Object.extend("ScoresCalc");
 var query = new Parse.Query(ScoresCalc);
 var currentTime = new Date();
 currentTime.setHours(0,0,0,0);

 var ScoresYesterday = Parse.Object.extend("ScoresYesterday");
 var queryScoresYesterday = new Parse.Query(ScoresYesterday);

 queryScoresYesterday.each(function(scoreYest){
 scoreYest.destroy();
 }).then(function(){
 query.each(function(scoreCalc) {

 var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("ScoresYesterday");
 var scoreyes = new GameScore();
 var PeopleCalc = scoreCalc.get("People");
 var QuestionCalc = scoreCalc.get("Question");
 var nbNotesCalc = scoreCalc.get("nbNotes");
 var totalNotesCalc = scoreCalc.get("totalNotes");


 scoreyes.set("People",PeopleCalc);
 scoreyes.set("Question",QuestionCalc);
 scoreyes.set("nbNotes",nbNotesCalc);
 scoreyes.set("totalNotes",totalNotesCalc);
 scoreyes.set("date", currentTime);

 return scoreyes.save();
 }).then(function() {
 // Set the job's success status
 status.success("Migration completed successfully.");
 }, function(error) {
 // Set the job's error status
 status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
 });
});
});
```

I'd like to know what is wrong with it.

EDIT: The changes I made with "when"

```
Parse.Cloud.job("deleteAndSaveScores2", function(request, status) {
  // Query for all scores
  var ScoresCalc = Parse.Object.extend("ScoresCalc");
  var query = new Parse.Query(ScoresCalc);
  var currentTime = new Date();
  currentTime.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var listOfPromises = [];

  var ScoresYesterday = Parse.Object.extend("ScoresYesterday");
  var queryScoresYesterday = new Parse.Query(ScoresYesterday);

  queryScoresYesterday.each(function(scoreYest){
    scoreYest.destroy();
  }).then(function(){
    query.each(function(scoreCalc) {

    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("ScoresYesterday");
    var scoreyes = new GameScore();
    var PeopleCalc = scoreCalc.get("People");
    var QuestionCalc = scoreCalc.get("Question");
    var nbNotesCalc = scoreCalc.get("nbNotes");
    var totalNotesCalc = scoreCalc.get("totalNotes");


    scoreyes.set("People",PeopleCalc);
    scoreyes.set("Question",QuestionCalc);
    scoreyes.set("nbNotes",nbNotesCalc);
    scoreyes.set("totalNotes",totalNotesCalc);
    scoreyes.set("date", currentTime);

    listOfPromises.push(scoreyes.save());
  })
}).then(function() {
  Parse.Promise.when(listOfPromises).then(function() {
     // Set the job's success status
    status.success("Migration completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
   });
});
});
```

Comment: Not sure you should be `return scoreyes.save();` from inside an `each`. More likely you should put all the save promises into an array and then wait for them all to complete at the end (after the `each`)

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it. If I add each scoreyes.save() in an array, how should I wait for each save to complete before returning a success or error ? Do I have to iterate over each one of theme ?

Comment: No, look at the promises API, there's a `when` method or something like that

Comment: I edited my post with the changes I made, I'll try that today, thanks !